# Sublime Text 2 bulk replace different items across multiple files from saved replace list

Tags: replace, sublimetext2

Suppose I have multiple text files open in Sublime Text 2.

In **a single operation** I want to replace according to the following list:

Across all open files, replace

- "foo" with "bar"
- "baz" with "qux"
- ... with ...
- etc.

Furthermore, I would like to be able to somehow **save/store the replace list** for later reuse.

Is there a way to do this, preferably without having to write a python script or recording a macro?

Comment: No, there is not a way to do this reading from a saved list except via a Python plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should look into Grunt.

Comment: In case somebody stumbles on it. It is possible in sublime text 3. Don't know about ST2.

Comment: Maverick, how is it done in ST3?